# How to get a reference to parent object from ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel

Tags: javafx

Hello I'm stuck on a point to get a reference to parent object containing ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel    Is it possible somehow to access it ?

I want to write single ChangeListener and register it for many ComboBoxes and then change pseudo class states inside ChangeListener object, but I need a reference to Object  for which it should be changed.

```
new ChangeListener<Object>() {

        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {

            if (observable instanceof ReadOnlyObjectProperty)
                ((ReadOnlyObjectProperty) observable).getBean();

        }
    };
```

This returns ComboBox$ComboBoxSelectionModel@7a1f9092    but how can I access the ComboBox object containing this selection model?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need a single change listener *instance*? Is there any reason not to use a different instance for each combo box? That way you can just pass a reference the combo box to the listener.

Comment: James_D, Actually I do not want to create to many instances and flood memory with them,   as there's slow increase in memory consumption on a constant basis in application application. So I'm trying to create as less instances as possible.

Comment: That's a premature optimization, imho. You would only be creating one listener for each text field, no more or less, and the listener would be eligible for garbage collection when the text field was. A listener instance has minimal state and the amount of memory consumed is minute compared to the text field itself. The listeners aren't going to create memory leaks - if they are present it's because you're retaining references to the text fields, not the listeners.

Comment: OMG  I did not know about that!    Many thanks for the tip about it.

Answer (score 0):

1) Use function ( James_D suggestion ) :

```
comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(getListener(comboBox));

ChangeListener<YourType> getListener(ComboBox<YourType> comboBox){
    return (o,ov,nv)->{
        // Use comboBox here
    };
}
```

2) Use reflection:

```
ChangeListener<YourType> listener = (o,ov,nv)->{
    try{
        ComboBox<?> comboBox = getCaller(o);
        ...
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        ...
    }
}
ComboBox<?> getCaller(ObservableValue<?> observable) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    final Object bean = ((ReadOnlyProperty<?>)observable).getBean();
    final Class<?> selectionModelClass = bean.getClass();
    final Field field = selectionModelClass.getDeclaredField("comboBox");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    return (ComboBox<?>) field.get(bean);
}
```

To get ChoiceBox use: selectionModelClass.getDeclaredField("choiceBox");